# Stylesheet is not getting linked when using EJS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have this code, for my `ejs page:`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link href="img/logo/logo.png" rel="icon">
  <title>RuangAdmin - Dashboard</title>
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/ruang-admin.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="page-top">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav sidebar sidebar-light accordion" id="accordionSidebar">
      <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.html">
        <div class="sidebar-brand-icon">
          <img src="img/logo/logo2.png">
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">RuangAdmin</div>
      </a>
      <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
          <span>Dashboard</span></a>
      </li>
      <hr class="sidebar-divider">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">
        Features
      </div>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBootstrap"
          aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseBootstrap">
          <i class="far fa-fw fa-window-maximize"></i>
          <span>Bootstrap UI</span>
        </a>
        <div id="collapseBootstrap" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingBootstrap" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
          <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
            <h6 class="collapse-header">Bootstrap UI</h6>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="alerts.html">Alerts</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="dropdowns.html">Dropdowns</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="modals.html">Modals</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="popovers.html">Popovers</a>
            <a class="collapse-item" href="progress-bar.html">Progress Bars</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
                    <div class="text-truncate">Am I a good boy? The reason I ask is because someone told me that people
                      say this to all dogs, even if they aren't good...</div>
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Jaenab · 2w</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">Read More Messages</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow mx-1">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="messagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="fas fa-tasks fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="badge badge-success badge-counter">3</span>
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-list dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header">
                  Task
                </h6>
                <a class="dropdown-item align-items-center" href="#">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Design Button
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>50%</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item align-items-center" href="#">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Make Beautiful Transitions
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>30%</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item align-items-center" href="#">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Create Pie Chart
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>75%</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-center small text-gray-500" href="#">View All Taks</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="img/boy.png" style="max-width: 60px">
                <span class="ml-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-white small">Maman Ketoprak</span>
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-user fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                  Profile
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-cogs fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                  Settings
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="fas fa-list fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                  Activity Log
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
                  <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                  Logout
                </a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Topbar -->

        <!-- Container Fluid-->
        <div class="container-fluid" id="container-wrapper">
          <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Dashboard</h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="./">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Dashboard</li>
            </ol>
          </div>

          <div class="row mb-3">
            <!-- Earnings (Monthly) Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-1">Earnings (Monthly)</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">$40,000</div>
                      <div class="mt-2 mb-0 text-muted text-xs">
                        <span class="text-success mr-2"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> 3.48%</span>
                        <span>Since last month</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-calendar fa-2x text-primary"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Earnings (Annual) Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-1">Sales</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">650</div>
                      <div class="mt-2 mb-0 text-muted text-xs">
                        <span class="text-success mr-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i> 12%</span>
                        <span>Since last years</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x text-success"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- New User Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-1">New User</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 mr-3 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">366</div>
                      <div class="mt-2 mb-0 text-muted text-xs">
                        <span class="text-success mr-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i> 20.4%</span>
                        <span>Since last month</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-users fa-2x text-info"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Pending Requests Card Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col mr-2">
                      <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-1">Pending Requests</div>
                      <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">18</div>
                      <div class="mt-2 mb-0 text-muted text-xs">
                        <span class="text-danger mr-2"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i> 1.10%</span>
                        <span>Since yesterday</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto">
                      <i class="fas fa-comments fa-2x text-warning"></i>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Area Chart -->
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7">
              <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Monthly Recap Report</h6>
                  <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-sm fa-fw text-gray-400"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in"
                      aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                      <div class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header:</div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="chart-area">
                    <canvas id="myAreaChart"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Pie Chart -->
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
              <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Products Sold</h6>
                  <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
                      data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Month <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in"
                      aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                      <div class="dropdown-header">Select Periode</div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Today</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Week</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Month</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">This Year</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Oblong T-Shirt
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>600 of 800 Items</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria-valuenow="80"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Gundam 90'Editions
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>500 of 800 Items</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 70%" aria-valuenow="70"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Rounded Hat
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>455 of 800 Items</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 55%" aria-valuenow="55"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Indomie Goreng
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>400 of 800 Items</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <div class="small text-gray-500">Remote Control Car Racing
                      <div class="small float-right"><b>200 of 800 Items</b></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 12px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%" aria-valuenow="30"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center">
                  <a class="m-0 small text-primary card-link" href="#">View More <i
                      class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Invoice Example -->
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7 mb-4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Invoice</h6>
                  <a class="m-0 float-right btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="#">View More <i
                      class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Order ID</th>
                        <th>Customer</th>
                        <th>Item</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA0449</a></td>
                        <td>Udin Wayang</td>
                        <td>Nasi Padang</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA5324</a></td>
                        <td>Jaenab Bajigur</td>
                        <td>Gundam 90' Edition</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-warning">Shipping</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA8568</a></td>
                        <td>Rivat Mahesa</td>
                        <td>Oblong T-Shirt</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-danger">Pending</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA1453</a></td>
                        <td>Indri Junanda</td>
                        <td>Hat Rounded</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-info">Processing</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">RA1998</a></td>
                        <td>Udin Cilok</td>
                        <td>Baby Powder</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Delivered</span></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Detail</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message From Customer-->
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 ">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header py-4 bg-primary d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-light">Message From Customer</h6>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="customer-message align-items-center">
                    <a class="font-weight-bold" href="#">
                      <div class="text-truncate message-title">Hi there! I am wondering if you can help me with a
                        problem I've been having.</div>
                      <div class="small text-gray-500 message-time font-weight-bold">Udin Cilok · 58m</div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="customer-message align-items-center">
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="text-truncate message-title">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea
                      </div>
                      <div class="small text-gray-500 message-time">Nana Haminah · 58m</div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="customer-message align-items-center">
                    <a class="font-weight-bold" href="#">
                      <div class="text-truncate message-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                      </div>
                      <div class="small text-gray-500 message-time font-weight-bold">Jajang Cincau · 25m</div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="customer-message align-items-center">
                    <a class="font-weight-bold" href="#">
                      <div class="text-truncate message-title">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos
                        ducimus qui blanditiis
                      </div>
                      <div class="small text-gray-500 message-time font-weight-bold">Udin Wayang · 54m</div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-footer text-center">
                    <a class="m-0 small text-primary card-link" href="#">View More <i
                        class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Row-->

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
              <p>Do you like this template ? you can download from <a href="https://github.com/indrijunanda/RuangAdmin"
                  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-fw fa-github"></i>&nbsp;GitHub</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal Logout -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelLogout"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelLogout">Ohh No!</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Are you sure you want to logout?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <a href="login.html" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!---Container Fluid-->
      </div>
      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
        <div class="container my-auto">
          <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
            <span>copyright &copy; <script> document.write(new Date().getFullYear()); </script> - developed by
              <b><a href="https://indrijunanda.gitlab.io/" target="_blank">indrijunanda</a></b>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- Footer -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scroll to top -->
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>

  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ruang-admin.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>  
</body>

</html>
```

Just a regular page that is called `dashboard.ejs`. the file structure is like so:
[image]

In the `views` folder, i have this `dashboard.ejs` page inside of it. in my `index.js` file, i have this:

```
 //defining applications necessities
const {
        response
      } = require("express");
      var express = require("express");
      const session = require('express-session');
    var ibmdb = require("ibm_db");
      const {
        render,
        name
      } = require("ejs");
      const {
        resolveSoa,
        CONNREFUSED
      } = require("dns");
      const {
        Console
      } = require("console");
       const path = require('path');
      
      //DEFINING APP SETTINGS
      const app = express();
      app.set("view engine", "ejs");
      app.use(express.static("public"));
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
      app.use("/public/css/images", express.static("./public/css/images"));
      app.use(express.json());
      app.use(
        express.urlencoded({
            extended: true,
        })
      );
```

problem is, when i run this, and i try to go to `dashboard.ejs`, it looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure why it is not rendering the CSS properly. The CSS is in `public/css`, and I've defined that route in the `index.js` file, and it is in the root directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the network tab and see if the request is going through.

Comment: @skara9 i get a 404 but for the fonts, which is fine becasue i didn't import that file. but no other errors.

Comment: Don't look for errors, just look for the request for your css file.

Comment: no requests at all. went to the network tab, and nothing

Comment: The link begins by 'vendor', but the 'vendor' folder is not configure to appear as public static in app.js... One way is to simlink, another is to make public the vendor folder...